# Error in sql Where clause equal to variable from arguments function

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I want to pop a list view with 2 linked tables for this I have created the next sql:

```
public static Cursor ListViewTimeStudy(String passedReg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String sql = "SELECT "
                    + "elements._id,"
                    + "elements.idstudy,"
                    + "elements.code_element,"
                    + "times._id,"
                    + "times.idelement,"                    
                    + "times.observedtime,"
                    + "times.observedactivity"
                    + " FROM "
                    + "elements JOIN times"
                    + " ON "
                    + "elements._id = times.idelement"
                    + " WHERE "
                    + "elements.idstudy = passedReg"
                    + " ORDER BY "
                    + "times._id DESC";



            Cursor mCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);

            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }
```

The result should show a table with fields from both tables and only the rows where elements.idstudy is equal to the variable passed in arguments of the function but in this issue I receive an error.

Comment: Try looking at this line "elements.idstudy = passedReg"  I think it should be "elements.idstudy = "+passedReg  since you are using the variable and not the actual string passedReg.

Comment: Will help a lot if you post the error message. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java and SQL are two separate languages; they don't automatically see each other's variables.

To pass a string value into an SQL query, use parameters:

```
String sql = "SELECT ..."
        + " WHERE idstudy = ?"
        + "...";
cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] { passedReg });
```